# Trying to pass information from 4 fields in an Android app to a String in java for testing connection prior to saving the information

Tags: java, android, mysql

I'm programing an android app that connects to a MySQL server, so far I have it so the user can enter the server ip, database name, user name and password and store it to the phone.  I am trying to build a string off the info the user just entered to test the connection prior to saving to the .txt files. I know it's probably right in front of my face but after a day of this I'm stuck, please help!!  The problem is located in the 'TestButtonListener'

```
public class AppInfo extends Activity {

public static final String DEBUGTAG = "It's Broke";
public static final String DATABASEPASSWORD = "pinfo.txt";
public static final String SERVERIP = "sinfo.txt";
public static final String DATABASEUSER = "ninfo.txt";
public static final String DATABASE = "dinfo.txt";
public static final String FILESAVED = "filesaved";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_info);
    addTestButtonListener();


///Test connection
private void addTestButtonListener() {
    Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.testcon);
    test.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
 ///need information from the R.id.server, R.id.database, R.id.name, R.id.pword
 /// and insert it into the string as serverIp, dataBase, name, pword.
 ///
             try {
              /// everything I've tried in here spits out the name of the text file, 
              /// or the memory address, but not the value just typed in.
            }

            String serverConnect = new String("jdbc:mysql://" + serverIp
                    + "/" + dataBase + ", " + name + ", " + pword);

            Toast.makeText(AppInfo.this, serverConnect, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: your snippet is too long. Would like to help you but don't want to read all these lines to find the problem... Can you provide important and only useful lines ?

Comment: what are you storing in the file? db username and pass? why not store them in the app preferences?

Comment: I'm trying to grab the information that the user just typed in to make sure it works before saving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't bother, I figured out how to fix it with .getText().toString() and after all that come to find out Android DOES NOT WORK with jdbc connector.